# how to get the largest of values in group by sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table, table contain `OperationDate`,`LotID`,`NewStatusID`,`opeTypeId`

I want to show `OperationDate`(top1) for every lot.

my query like this:

```
      select a.OperationDate,a.LotID
  FROM  [dbo].[MMwLotOperations]   a
  where   a.LotID in ('L705816008','L704511001')
    GROUP by a.LotID,a.OperationDate 
 having  a.NewStatusID ='Assigned' AND a.opeTypeId = 'Status'
```

this query returns these data:

[image]

*L705816008* lot's `NewStatusID` returns 1 data

but *L704511001* lot's `NewStatusID`  returns 2 data

now I want to show the biggest `OperationDate` for every lot.
how can do this?

could you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `MAX` to get the largest date and remove `a.OperationDate` from `Group By`

```
select MAX(a.OperationDate),a.LotID
FROM  [dbo].[MMwLotOperations]   a
where   a.LotID in ('L705816008','L704511001')
        AND a.NewStatusID ='Assigned' AND a.opeTypeId = 'Status' 
GROUP by a.LotID
```

**NOTE**: [Having](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-having-transact-sql) specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate.
In your case, put `a.NewStatusID ='Assigned' AND a.opeTypeId = 'Status'` to `where` condition

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(   select a.OperationDate,a.LotID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by a.LotID ORDER BY a.OperationDate desc) as rn
  FROM  [dbo].[MMwLotOperations]   a
  where   a.LotID in ('L705816008','L704511001')
    GROUP by a.LotID,a.OperationDate 
 having  a.NewStatusID ='Assigned' AND a.opeTypeId = 'Status' ) where rn =1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 select MAX(a.OperationDate) as max_date,a.LotID
  FROM  [dbo].[MMwLotOperations]   a
  where   a.LotID in ('L705816008','L704511001')
    GROUP by a.LotID,a.OperationDate
 having  a.NewStatusID ='Assigned' AND a.opeTypeId = 'Status'
```

Try this statement to get the max date

Answer (score 0):

use distinct keyword to select a.LotID

```
select a.OperationDate,distinct(a.LotID)
FROM  [dbo].[MMwLotOperations]   a
 where   a.LotID in ('L705816008','L704511001')
GROUP by a.LotID,a.OperationDate 
having  a.NewStatusID ='Assigned' AND a.opeTypeId = 'Status'
```

i hope this will work for you